# Fetch areas for OSM nodes / ways from Overpass using relation IDs

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to fetch up to around 10 OSM objects and assign them to a set of hand-picked areas (up to around 20 different areas) in a single Overpass query. Is this possible?

So the desired output is:

1. Node/Way tags and center of first object + area the first object is in
2. Node/Way tags and center of first object + area the first object is in
3. ...

I already got this kind of working with wikidata tags:

```
[out:json][timeout:10];
(
node(id:3959878839);way(id:162817836);
);
foreach->.d(
  (.d;.d >;)->.d; 
  .d out center;
  .d is_in;
  area._[wikidata~"(Q14201325|Q16895860)"];
  out;
);
>;
```

[Overpass Turbo](https://turbo.overpass.kumi.systems/?Q=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A10%5D%3B%0A(%0Anode(id%3A3959878839)%3Bway(id%3A162817836)%3B%0A)%3B%0Aforeach-%3E.d(%0A%20%20(.d%3B.d%20%3E%3B)-%3E.d%3B%20%0A%20%20.d%20out%20center%3B%0A%20%20.d%20is_in%3B%0A%20%20area._%5Bwikidata%7E%22(Q14201325%7CQ16895860)%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20out%3B%0A)%3B%0A%3E%3B&C=8.97881;38.78015;14)

This returns the node / way data as well as the area the object is in.

Now I realized I cannot identify all areas needed in the future by wikidata tags and want to use the relation IDs.

The relations are:

- https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/11589457
- https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/11589616

For area IDs we have to add [3600000000 to the ID](http://osmlab.github.io/learnoverpass/en/docs/filters/area/).

So I tried

```
[out:json][timeout:10];
(
node(id:3959878839);way(id:162817836);
);
foreach->.d(
(.d;.d >;)->.d;
.d out center;
.d is_in;
area._area(3611589457);
out;
);
>;
```

[Overpass Turbo](https://turbo.overpass.kumi.systems/?Q=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A10%5D%3B%0A(%0Anode(id%3A3959878839)%3Bway(id%3A162817836)%3B%0A)%3B%0Aforeach-%3E.d(%0A%20%20(.d%3B.d%20%3E%3B)-%3E.d%3B%20%0A%20%20.d%20out%20center%3B%0A%20%20.d%20is_in%3B%0Aarea._area(3611589457)%3B%0A%20%20out%3B%0A)%3B%0A%3E%3B&C=8.97717;38.76179;18)

But this does not output the area any more, and I also don't know how to supply the other area IDs here.

Comment: The documentation you've quoted here is outdated and not the original one (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_(area) ... "For area IDs we have to add 3600000000 to the ID." -> this is no longer recommended: "You should use the map_to_area function to avoid having to make these calculations manually and depend on any hard-coded constants in your query. "

Answer (score 2):

So I just read [the tutorial first](https://osm-queries.ldodds.com/tutorial/index.html). (shame on me I did not do this earlier)

This works:

```
[out:json][timeout:10];
(
node(id:3959878839);way(id:162817836);
);
foreach->.d(
  .d out center;
  (.d;.d >;)->.d;   
  .d is_in -> .areas;
  ( 
    area(3611589457).areas;
    area(3611589616).areas;  
  );
  out;
);
>;
```

Also I put the recurse query after printing the features, because I do not need the nodes of the ways in the output.

[Overpass Turbo](https://turbo.overpass.kumi.systems/?Q=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A10%5D%3B%0A(%0Anode(id%3A3959878839)%3Bway(id%3A162817836)%3B%0A)%3B%0Aforeach-%3E.d(%0A%20%20.d%20out%20center%3B%0A%20%20(.d%3B.d%20%3E%3B)-%3E.d%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20.d%20is_in%20-%3E%20.areas%3B%0A%20%20(%20%0A%20%20%20%20area(3611589457).areas%3B%0A%20%20%09area(3611589616).areas%3B%20%20%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20out%3B%0A)%3B%0A%3E%3B)